# Error on Crystal Report 10.5.3700.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a web application which is using Crystal Report for generating different reports.

Application was working correctly in Production server (Windows Server 2003). Recently we updated our P server to Windows Server 2008 R2 and after that all the Crystal Report functionality stopped working.

Throwing error like :

> the type initializer for
>   'crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine.reportdocument' threw an
>   exception.

I had updated the App poll settings also to allow 32 bit application to true and from VS 2008 right click Properties, On the Build tab to "Any CPU".

The issue is in a Production site.